# contextInitialized method in servletcontextlistener

Tags: java

contextInitialized method of servletcontextlistener is called when the web application initialization process starts. Is ServletContextListener is related to servlet in any ways(as per its name). Because this is called even if do not write any servlet in my web application.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it's just an interface for receiving notification events about ServletContext lifecycle changes.

There is the `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener` Interface for receiving notification events about requests coming into and going out of scope of a web application servlets.